# Ordenar un array de objetos a partir de una propiedad que hay en un array de objetos interno

Tags: javascript, ordenamiento

Estoy tratando de ordenar un objeto pero no me está saliendo.

Supongamos que tengo tres objetos en un array:

```
let arr = [
  {
   id: 1,
   tipos: [{id_vista: 10, nombre: "emprendimiento", orden: 2}]
  },
  {
   id: 3,
   tipos: [{id_vista: 10, nombre: "emprendimiento", orden: 3}, {id_vista: 12, nombre: "edificio", 
   orden: 1}]
  },
  {
   id:2,
   tipos: [{id_vista: 8, nombre: "desarrollo", orden: 10}, {id_vista: 10, nombre: "emprendimiento", 
   orden: 1}]
  }
 ]
```

Ahora, como veran, tengo el array "Tipos", que es una propiedad. El tipo me indica que este objeto se listará en una o mas vistas, por ejemplo:

El de id 1 se va a listar en Emprendimientos

El de id 2 se va a listar en Desarrollos y Emprendimientos

El de id 3 se va a listar en Emprendimientos y Edificios

Supongamos que yo me encuentro en la vista de emprendimientos, y deseo ordenar el array `arr` de acuerdo con la propiedad `orden` que se encuentra en el objeto que se encuentra en el array `tipos`, que tiene el `id_vista` 10 (correspondiente a emprendimientos).
Debería quedarme (según sus `ids`) el 2, luego el 1 y finalmente el 3.

Esto es lo que estoy intentando pero no me funciona:

```js
   let arr = [
      {
       id: 1,
       tipos: [{id: 10, nombre: "emprendimiento", orden: 2}]
      },
      {
       id: 3,
       tipos: [{id: 10, nombre: "emprendimiento", orden: 3}, {id: 12, nombre: "edificio", 
       orden: 1}]
      },
      {
       id:2,
       tipos: [{id: 8, nombre: "desarrollo", orden: 10}, {id: 10, nombre: "emprendimiento", 
       orden: 1}]
      }
     ]

  arr.sort((a,b) => {
          b.tipos.map(e => 
          {
            if(e.id == 10){
              a.tipos.map(f => {
                if(f.id == 10){
                  return e.orden - f.orden
                }
              })
            }
          })
        })
        
        console.log(arr)
```

> Estoy obteniendo el mismo array sin ordenar.

Comment: ¿Qué criterio usas para ordenar si el objeto no contiene la vista en donde estás? Por ejemplo si quieres ordenar por "desarrollo", ¿cómo sería? Porque desarrollo no está en los dos primeros elementos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la función que le pasas a sort, primero debes buscar el elemento correspondiente a la vista donde estás, y luego encontrar el orden de ese elemento. Con eso, ya el array quedará ordenado como quieres.

Una cosa importante es que este método fallará si el elemento no tiene la vista requerida, ya que no hay manera de que sort sepa con qué comparar.

```js
let arr = [
      {
       id: 1,
       tipos: [{id: 10, nombre: "emprendimiento", orden: 2}]
      },
      {
       id: 3,
       tipos: [{id: 10, nombre: "emprendimiento", orden: 3}, {id: 12, nombre: "edificio", 
       orden: 1}]
      },
      {
       id:2,
       tipos: [{id: 8, nombre: "desarrollo", orden: 10}, {id: 10, nombre: "emprendimiento", 
       orden: 1}]
      }
     ]

  let idVista = 10;
  arr.sort((a,b) => {
    let aOrden = a.tipos.find(element => element.id == idVista).orden
    let bOrden = b.tipos.find(element => element.id == idVista).orden
    return  aOrden - bOrden
  })
        
console.log(arr)
```